# How open connection with indexedDB for Cypress tests?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I want to test my app that use indexedDB, and becouse of indexedDB my tests dont work,
shoud I set up indexedDB for tests, and what correct way to do it.

My code

```
beforeEach(() => {

cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url :'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login',
  body : {
    email: "name",
    password: "Passwprd"
  }
}).then(function(response) {

  loadScript('https://unpkg.com/localforage@1.5.5/dist/localforage.js').then(() => {
    
    window.indexedDB.open("testDB");
    
    localforage.config({
      driver: [localforage.INDEXEDDB],
      name: 'timesheetstestDBDB',
      storeName: 'testDB',
      version: '1.0',
    });
  })
   localforage.clear().then(() => {
    localforage.setItem('jobs', [{name: 'fdf'}]);
  });
}).then(()=>{
  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/');
})
```

})

Component that I want to test use indexedDB requests for first component load, and I get error from cypress

```
Unhandled Rejection (OpenFailedError): UnknownError Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open.
 UnknownError: Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open.
```

I just want to now way to run tests, and open indexedDB connection for end to end cypress enviroment.

Normal queries to the server work fine in automatic mode, but on queries to the indexedDB tests fail, because in the environment that opens cypress indexedDB is not open.

I run my app as  `"cypress": "cypress open"` in package.json file

[image]

Comment: Please add your code that you tried.

Comment: I use Dexie as wrapper for indexedDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IndexedDB can be manipulated easily from Cypress by using [localforage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/#settings-api-config) package. I'm using it to set things like the `access_token` inside the IndexedDB. Example:

```
import localforage from 'localforage';

const setAccessToken = (token: string) => {
  cy.log('Setting access token in IndexedDB');
  
  localforage.clear().then(() => {
    localforage.setItem('access_token', token);
  });

};

const generateAccessToken = (user: string, password: string) => {
  cy.log(`Generating new access token for: "${user}"`);
  cy.request('POST', `${Cypress.env('AUTH_SERVICE')}/login`, {
    login: user,
    password: password,
  }).its('body').then((res) => {
    setAccessToken(res.token);
    Cypress.env(`${user}_access_token`, res.token);
  });
};

Cypress.Commands.add("login", (user, password) => {
  if (Cypress.env(`${user}_access_token`)){
    cy.log(`Using cached access token for: "${user}"`);
    setAccessToken(Cypress.env(`${user}_access_token`))
  } else generateAccessToken(user, password);
});
```

Comment: but my tests fails and I guess it becaue of indexedDB does not set up in my tests, the question is not about how get access but about how open connection with indexedDB, or maybe I understand something wrong

Comment: Hey @Ksenia In my example from above I'm opening a connection with the IndexedDB and I'm setting up a value in it. Check out `localforage` docs to learn more about setting up a custom connection with an IndexedDB.

Comment: pls, I mark question as resolved, but I still get next error( I updated quetion)

Comment: I try to use many methods but because of my component go to the indexedDb to get some data on page my tests fail

Comment: Can you give some link where you set up inexedDB pls(

Comment: In order to use  localforage.setItem('access_token', token); at first I  questt we need initialize indexedDB in brawser in tests

Comment: I create one more topic for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69196270/error-when-try-open-connection-with-indexeddb-in-cypress