# Error when try open connection with indexedDB in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I make request to server for login, and then before redirect user to home page I try to
open indexedDB connection in order to see this page, bacause home page go to the indexedDB
and get some data. So below is my code and photo of error

```
    beforeEach(() => {
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url :'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login',
      body : {
        email: "email",
        password: "password"
      }
    }).then(function(response) {



        window.indexedDB.open("testDB");

        localforage.config({
          driver: [localforage.INDEXEDDB],
          name: 'testDB',
          storeName: 'testDB',
          version: '1.0',
        });
    
      
      localforage.clear().then(() => {
        localforage.setItem('jobs', [{name: 'fdf'}]);
      });
    }).then(()=>{
      cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/');
    })
  })
```

[image]

I also try this way but it doesnt works too, what I do wrong?

```
function open() {
  var request = window.indexedDB.open("testDB", 1);
  request.onerror = function(event) {
   
  };
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  };

  request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;

    var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("jobs", { keyPath: "name" });

    objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
    objectStore.add({name: 'fsdf'});
  }
}

describe('The Login Page', () => {


  beforeEach(() => {
    open()
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url :'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login',
      body : {
        email: "gfdgfdg",
        password: "gdfgfdg"
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {

    })
        .then(()=>{
      cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/');
    })
  })
```

Comment: I can add additional code if it is necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that is (probably) incorrect is the `window` reference.

Cypress runs the browser window as an automation "shell", which is what you get when you use

```js
window.indexedDB.open("testDB")
```

but the app window is inside an iframe.

You can access either with

```js
cy.window().then(win => win.indexedDB.open("testDB"))
```

or

```js
cy.state('window').indexedDB.open("testDB")  // undocumented!
```